# Optimal bound for cost of cut elimination in infinitary logic with transfinite cut-rank in terms of Veblen's $\varphi$ function

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

The theorem I am referring to is Tait's sharpening of Gentzen's Cut Elimination Theorem in [1], which Schütte [2, p. 204, Theorem 22.8] also calls the ``second cut elimination theorem'' (here written in the Tait-style calculus, which derives finite sets--interpreted as disjunctions--of possibly infinitary formulae, also comp. [3, pp. 52f., p. 116]):

$$\text{If  } \vdash^{\alpha}_{\beta+\omega^\rho} \Delta 
\text{   then  }\vdash^{\varphi_\rho(\alpha)}_{\beta} \Delta,$$

where $\varphi_\rho (\alpha)$ refers to the Veblen function, comp [4], [6], and $\vdash^{\alpha}_{\beta} \Delta$ means that there is a derivation of $\Delta$ with height $\leq \alpha$  and cut-rank $< \beta$.

The proof proceeds by a nested induction, the main induction on $\rho$ (induction hypothesis: claim holds for all $\xi < \rho$), the side induction on $\alpha$ (ind. hyp.: claim holds for $\rho$ and all $\alpha_0 < \alpha$), and exploits the fact that for any $\sigma < \rho$, $\alpha_0 < \alpha$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\underbrace{\varphi_\sigma(\varphi_\sigma(...}_\text{n-fold}(\varphi_\rho(\alpha_0)+1)...)$$

is majorized by $\varphi_\rho(\alpha)$. This allows to finish the proof.

Now my question is this: I have seen it stated more than once (without argument) that the above result is *optimal*, in the sense that the 'cost' of eliminating cuts cannot be measured by functions that grow any slower than $\varphi$ (e.g. [5]). This seems to be a somewhat vague claim, and not at all obvious. Can this be made more precise, and can it be proven?

**Extra question** | On a more general note, I must admit that I do not have a very clear intuition of the Veblen functions. I understand their introduction in terms of enumerating fixed points of normal functions, but to be honest, beyond this purely abstract conceptual grasp, I can't really imagine what they 'look like'. Can anyone, actually? Honestly I am already struggling to put a clear intuition to $\varepsilon_0$ (although I can calculate with it quite well), of which I have read that ''it is easy to visualize'' and *therefore* ''plain'' that transfinite induction is valid for it [3, p.130]. Now I have no trouble ''visualizing'' hydras or various orderings on finite trees or ordinal *notation* systems for $\varepsilon_0$ (which convince me of its well-foundedness), but the order type itself? Either I'm (literally) overlooking something ''plain'' and obvious, or this is a massive overstatement. I can't 'see' $\varepsilon_0$, and I certainly can't 'see' what the effect of iterating $\varphi$ 'looks like'. Do you have any suggestions for sharpening my eyes?

---

[1] W. W. Tait. 1968, Normal derivability in classical logic. In: Jon Barwise, ed., The Syntax and Semantics of Infinitary Languages LNM 72. (Berlin: Springer, 1968), pp. 204-236.

[2] K. Schütte. 1977, Proof Theory, Berlin: Springer.

[3] W. Pohlers. 2009, Proof Theory: The First Step into Impredicativity, Berlin: Springer.

[4] https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/index.html#StroOrdiReprVeblBachHier

[5] https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/index.html#InfiProoForPredTheo

[6] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function

Comment: I'd be really surprised if there's a good concrete intuition for $\varepsilon_0$, since it comes mainly from a very particular set of considerations. And having lived with Pohlers's book for a few months now, I can say I would definitely not trust his opinion on what is "easy" or "clear" :P

Comment: Is Pohler's the only text you are working with? I must say, in combination with Schütte and Takeuti, I find it to be extremely good learning material. Yes, you have to work out the idea behind almost everything yourself, as he barely gives any detailed expositions, but that just forces you to actually reason through the proofs. Are you studying it just for fun, or are you seriously working on something with it?

Comment: I actually also have Schutte and Takeuti, though honestly even between the three of them I don't think I saw a picture emerge until reading some lecture notes by Rathjen. I'm 50/50 reading them for a project on ordinal analysis for the last year of my undergraduate degree, and doing it for fun :P

Comment: I have in mind a set of lecture notes that seem to be closely related to [these](http://scandinavianlogic.org/material/Nordic_LectureNotes.pdf). (The exact document I have doesn't seem to be online, but he'd probably send them to you on request.) Of course, you seem to be well past the thing that was tripping me up (what the heck the semi-formal system is actually telling us), so I'm not sure they'll be as revelatory to you as they were for me.

Comment: Thank you! That looks quite useful indeed, but probably best is just to ask him directly, I'll do that. Is he a teacher of yours?

Comment: No, I just sort of emailed him out of the blue and asked if he could spare a minute :P He was pleasant enough about it.